# How to display the soap xml message before it's send using laravel-soap

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I managed to use [laravel-soap](https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap) to send and receive requests, but for debugging purposes I want to print/echo the exact xml being send and received.

I tried to use

```
->trace(true);
```

but that doesn't seem to help.

So how do I print out the actual soap xml message being send and received

**Update: This is my code**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper;
class IsController extends Controller {
public function demo()
{
// Add a new service to the wrapper
SoapWrapper::add(function ($service) {
   $service
   ->name('Test')
   ->wsdl('http://link.to.provider/program.asmx?wsdl')
   ->trace(true);
 });
$data = [
     'UserName' => 'XXXXXXX',
     'Password'   => 'XXXXXXX',
    ];
// Using the added service
SoapWrapper::service('Test', function ($service) use ($data) {
//var_dump($service->getFunctions());

var_dump($service->getLastRequest());

//dd($service->call('Login', [$data]));

//dd($service->getLastResponse());

});
}
}
```

I already tried replacing

```
echo htmlentities($service->getLastResponse());
```

with

```
dd($service->getLastResponse());
```

and

```
var_dump($service->getLastResponse());
```

The result is the; same the text "NULL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to echo it out, try this;

```
echo htmlentities($service->getLastRequest());
```

And, for the response:

```
echo htmlentities($service->getLastResponse());
```

Comment: this only results in the text "NULL", nothing else, for both

Comment: Just today my provider is down. I will have to test another time

Comment: @davejal yeah, if it's null, that means there is no response from your provider

Comment: I think google's dns is part of the problem at the moment